CORS Error When Trying to Connect to Firebase Function from Localhost Frontend. React, Firebase - Stripe
I'm currently working on integrating Stripe with Firebase functions for a project running on localhost. I've set up a Firebase function to create a Stripe Verification Session and return a client secret to the frontend. However, I'm encountering a CORS error when trying to fetch this client secret from my frontend running on a different port.
Here’s the error I’m receiving:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/x/us-central1/createVerificationSession' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Additionally, I'm seeing a network error:
POST http://localhost:5001/x/us-central1/createVerificationSession net::ERR_FAILED

Here is the relevant part of my Firebase function:
exports.createVerificationSession = onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'unauthenticated',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    );
  }

  try {
    const verificationSession = await stripe.identity.verificationSessions.create({
      type: 'document',
      metadata: { user_id: context.auth.uid },
    });
    return { clientSecret: verificationSession.client_secret };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Stripe Error:', error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create verification session', error);
  }
});

I am using callable functions from Firebase, which I thought handled CORS automatically. My frontend is making requests from http://localhost:5173 to the Firebase function hosted at http://localhost:5001.
Here's what I get in the network tab

Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong and how to correctly set up CORS for this setup? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

When you go in the network tab -> request, is it 200 OK or blocked?

@Dimitar thanks or the reply, I get 2 CORS erros and 2 404 so maybe something wrong there? Appreciate the help. Have updated OP to show
